# echo json_encode after mysql_query failure

Tags: php, android

I'm currently trying to develop an Android app that communicates with a database. I use php scripts to communicate between my app and the database.

For error handling purposes, I was wondering if I could replace the die() function in php with something simliar to json_encode so that I can send an error code to my app.

```
mysql_query(/*the query*/) or /* something like echo json_encode*/
```

EDIT: here's an example of what I usually use,

```
$response['error1'] = "error in select query";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_product FROM `product`where id_category=$id_category") or die(mysql_error());
```

I tried something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_product FROM `product`where id_category=$id_category") or die(echo json_encode($response));
```

It doesn't work and I would like to know whether there is something else I can use.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes you can. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Show what you have tried then. As is, this question is too broad and flagged as such.

Comment: Here it is =D.
EDIT: I've just tried what @Daan suggested and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if on the result. If `mysql_query()` fails it returns false:

```
$result = mysql_query(/*the query*/);

if(!$result){
  //Do stuff here, the query failed
  //json_encode()
} else {
  //Query succeeded
}
```

Sidenote: `mysql_*` is deprecated, I highly recommend to switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it generate the JSON array **loginsession**

```
  $return_arr = array();

//here start while loop for Mysql 

    $row_array['uid']=$uid;         
    $row_array['uname']=$uname;     
    $row_array['email']=$email;
    $row_array['phone']=$phnumb;
    $row_array['birthday']=$dob;
    $row_array['address']=$address;                                     
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

// end your while loop

    echo json_encode(array('loginsession' => $return_arr));
```